Buildozer fails on libffi
I am trying to make an APK from a simple Python GUI script.  I am using Raspberry Pi, as this is the only Linux system I have.  I had already solved two problems, but I stucked on this one. What should I do next?
PS. Installing Buildozer is so complex that it is not surprising at all that it is so unstable.  Why is making APKs from Python such impossible task?  Is that because Python is not meant to be compiled or because Python is not at good terms with Android?  Is it worth the effort at all, or would it be better to simply learn Java instead?

checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host
system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android checking target system
type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking
whether build environment is sane... yes checking for
aarch64-linux-android-strip...
/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip
--strip-unneeded checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... no checking for mawk... mawk checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes checking whether make -j4 supports nested
variables... yes checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc...
/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC checking whether the C compiler works... no configure: error: in /home/pi/apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See config.log' for more details
STDERR:
Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=nona',
'--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a',
'--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always',
'--storage-dir=/home/pi/apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a',
'--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
ENVIRONMENT:
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg'
XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'lxde-pi-'
LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
_LXSESSION_PID = '668'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-4vznLqEkVfmL/agent.668'
XDG_CONFIG_HOME = '/home/pi/.config'
DESKTOP_SESSION = 'LXDE-pi'
SSH_AGENT_PID = '720'
NO_AT_BRIDGE = '1'
XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
PWD = '/home/pi/apk'
LOGNAME = 'pi'
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'lightdm-xsession'
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
XAUTHORITY = '/home/pi/.Xauthority'
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm/data/pi'
HOME = '/home/pi'
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:.tar=01;31:.tgz=01;31:.arc=01;31:.arj=01;31:.taz=01;31:.lha=01;31:.lz4=01;31:.lzh=01;31:.lzma=01;31:.tlz=01;31:.txz=01;31:.tzo=01;31:.t7z=01;31:.zip=01;31:.z=01;31:.dz=01;31:.gz=01;31:.lrz=01;31:.lz=01;31:.lzo=01;31:.xz=01;31:.zst=01;31:.tzst=01;31:.bz2=01;31:.bz=01;31:.tbz=01;31:.tbz2=01;31:.tz=01;31:.deb=01;31:.rpm=01;31:.jar=01;31:.war=01;31:.ear=01;31:.sar=01;31:.rar=01;31:.alz=01;31:.ace=01;31:.zoo=01;31:.cpio=01;31:.7z=01;31:.rz=01;31:.cab=01;31:.wim=01;31:.swm=01;31:.dwm=01;31:.esd=01;31:.jpg=01;35:.jpeg=01;35:.mjpg=01;35:.mjpeg=01;35:.gif=01;35:.bmp=01;35:.pbm=01;35:.pgm=01;35:.ppm=01;35:.tga=01;35:.xbm=01;35:.xpm=01;35:.tif=01;35:.tiff=01;35:.png=01;35:.svg=01;35:.svgz=01;35:.mng=01;35:.pcx=01;35:.mov=01;35:.mpg=01;35:.mpeg=01;35:.m2v=01;35:.mkv=01;35:.webm=01;35:.webp=01;35:.ogm=01;35:.mp4=01;35:.m4v=01;35:.mp4v=01;35:.vob=01;35:.qt=01;35:.nuv=01;35:.wmv=01;35:.asf=01;35:.rm=01;35:.rmvb=01;35:.flc=01;35:.avi=01;35:.fli=01;35:.flv=01;35:.gl=01;35:.dl=01;35:.xcf=01;35:.xwd=01;35:.yuv=01;35:.cgm=01;35:.emf=01;35:.ogv=01;35:.ogx=01;35:.aac=00;36:.au=00;36:.flac=00;36:.m4a=00;36:.mid=00;36:.midi=00;36:.mka=00;36:.mp3=00;36:.mpc=00;36:.ogg=00;36:.ra=00;36:.wav=00;36:.oga=00;36:.opus=00;36:.spx=00;36:.xspf=00;36:'
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'LXDE'
VTE_VERSION = '6203'
XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
USER = 'pi'
DISPLAY = ':0'
SHLVL = '1'
XDG_VTNR = '7'
XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/fkms:/usr/local/share:/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg'
PATH = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.local/bin/'
GDMSESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN = 'gtk3'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
OLDPWD = '/home/pi/apk/bin'
TEXTDOMAIN = 'Linux-PAM'
_ = '/home/pi/.local/bin/buildozer'
PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/packages'
ANDROIDSDK = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
ANDROIDNDK = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
ANDROIDAPI = '31'
ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
Buildozer failed to execute the last command
The error might be hidden in the log above this error
Please read the full log, and search for it before
raising an issue with buildozer itself.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

